# Retrieving Last Consumption-Based Access Date for BigQuery Tables

Tags: google-bigquery

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm tackling an issue related to Google BigQuery and I'm hoping to tap into the expertise here.

Objective: I'm working on deprecating data pipelines that generate BigQuery tables without any consumption over the past X months. Consumption here refers to operations such as querying the tables, sinking data to other data storages, or retrieving data via APIs.

Challenge: While using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT, I observed that these schemas don't capture external dependencies related to the BigQuery tables. I've been delving into the audit_log and I'm in the midst of formulating a logical approach to obtain the desired data.

Question: Has anyone successfully retrieved the last consumption-based access date (excluding data insertion/creation activities) for BigQuery tables? If so, could you share your method or provide any pointers?

I appreciate any guidance or insights. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro), consider exploring a couple of methods related to this use case. The application will depend on which one fits your needs, check out these documents for more information.

- [jobs.getQueryResults](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults) - used to retrieve the results of a query job
- [tabledata.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list) - used to retrieve data directly from a BigQuery table